# meta charset vs document encoding

Tags: html

when I create an html document why is it still necessary to use the meta tag with the charset="utf-8" attribute within the html code when the html document itself was saved using utf-8 encoding? Isn't it like setting the same encoding twice? Thanks for answers.

Comment: The browser doesn't know what encoding the document uses unless you tell it.

Comment: Hm, what is the document encoding used for if it doesn't tell the browser which encoding I'm using?

Comment: For encoding the document? The question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make much sense, too. Obviously, you can't clearly answer what it does. For example, if I saved my file as .html using utf-8 encoding in the sublime text editor and then I will open the same file in another text editor, will the new text editor know how to display the html code properly because of the document encoding I set in sublime text? Is this what the document encoding is used for?

Comment: No. The information that the file has been saved in utf-8 does not exist in the file itself. The browser or other editor can try to guess, but the file itself doesn't say what encoding it uses.

Comment: Well, I just did a small test. I saved "hello" string in notepad using ansi encoding, then I saved the same string using utf-8 encoding. When I have a look at the hex values of those 2 files, the ansi one is showing: 68 65 6c 6c 6f. When you look up those hex codes in ASCII table you'll find out they stand for the letters "h", "e", "l", "l" and "o", which is fine and no information about encoding exists. However, the utf-8 file shows these values: ef bb bf 68 65 6c 6c 6f. As you can see, there are additional 3 bytes at the beginning.What those additional 3 bytes represent if not encoding type?

Comment: It's the byte order mark. It doesn't represent the encoding type.

Answer (score 1):

The charset of a resource transferred over HTTP defaults to ISO-8859-1 unless a charset override has been specified in the `Content-Type` header ([link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2)). Thus, you *have to* specify the document charset in you HTML if it is different from ISO-8859-1, for your browser to parse (and display) the document properly.